# How can i send mail by pdf url --REACT

Tags: reactjs, email, url, pdf-generation

I'm trying to send pdf links from the backend as a file (attachment), I searched and couldn't find any results. I will be glad if you help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using for backend? If it java , there is a library called sendMail.It could help